# session aware applications

Tags: session, tomcat, servlets

I intentionally wrote 'session aware' instead of 'session shared' applications. Following is a scenario:

I have a webapp (WA1) deployed in one instance of Tomcat.. Assume that all apps are deployed on root and we are not dealing with contexts. This application allows users to login, do their thing on site and logout.

There is another webapp (WA2) on another tomcat instance. This application handles a service, lets say, it reads some files and streams to the browser.

WA1 serves a page which has a link that links to WA2.

Now I have a valid session in WA1 which identifies who the user is and if the session is a valid session. I would like WA2 to know it before honoring the request from the page served by WA1.

What is the best way to handle this?

I have ruled out sharing sessions (unless that is the better way, please explain), due to the reason that WA1 could be itself load balanced and WA2 could be load balanced, and to keep shared sessions over two load balanced instances of the app may get overwhelming.

I am leaning towards a 'token' mechanism.. where WA1 creates a token associated with every session and makes it available to every url to WA2 from any page served from WA1. WA2 would first inspect the token, and see if it is a valid token (many ways to do this: A: make a web-service call to WA1 to ask if token is a valid session token.. B: WA1 persists to DB or file system and WA2 seeks from there.. ), and if it is valid, then honor the request.  The issue here would be to make sure that the token is invalidated when a session in WA1 expires.

I would like to know if this approach is good enough, or are there better ways to do this?

Thanks

M. Rather

Answer (score 1):

By default, the servlet API uses a cookie, typically named `jsessionid`, to store a session ID in each browser. Then, the browser passes the cookie to the server with each request. As long as both instances of tomcat are within the same domain, they should both have access to that cookie. Unless I'm missing something, it's just a matter of testing for that cookie in the second application.

**Update:** Even if each instance of tomcat runs in a different domain, they can still share these cookies by calling the `setDomain(String domainPattern)` method of the Cookie class.

Comment: Thanks elekwent, So basically it is similar to the 'token' method described, except that instead of using token+DB/web-service the jsessionId+cookie/browser is used to validate a valid session/token. For now we will have both the instances of tomcat on same domain, but I would like to know if WA2 could be on a different domain as well.

Comment: Yes, similar when you consider the end result which is to determine if a valid session exists. There is no session sharing going on here, or any other complex behavior. WA2 only needs to check for the jsessionid cookie to know if a session exists between the user's browser and any server on your domain. Use the cookie's setDomain() method to grant access to WA2 when it moves to another domain.

Comment: If we go with the cookie route, in WA2 we can read the cookie and get the jsessionid. How can one guarantee that the jsessionid is a valid jsessionid generated by a valid WA1 session. As I believe, cookies can be edited, and if a user creates a cookie with any dummy value for jessionid, and WA2 can find a cookie with 'a' value, this does not guarantee that it is a valid WA1 session. WA2 will have to still query somewhere to authenticate the jsessionid's value, which means WA1 would have to either respond to a request from WA2 or will have to persist somewhere where WA2 can read from.